# Getting error while adding values in jcomboBox

Tags: java

i am facing a little problem with this code. When i tried to retrieve some data from database table i created it works fine showing the data in console, but when i tried to see the data in my created comboBox it is showing some "null" exception. How To Solve it?

[When i tried to show values in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r47ry.png)

[When i tried to add the values in comboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4NQb.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can write code line this.. create object of frame and JComboBox and add value and the add object of JComboBox into frame.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JComboBox jComboBox1 = new JComboBox();
jComboBox1.addItem("asdf");
Object cmboitem = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
System.out.println(cmboitem);

frame.add(jComboBox1);

frame.setSize(300, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not a problem with combo box but with the connection to the database.
The exception happens (and therefore your program stops) before the combo box line.

EDIT:
Print the whole exception trace please.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have solved the problem. It seems i have used a pair of curly braces in wrong way. After Correctly putting the braces it solved the problem.